# frozenset and tuple inside itself

Tags: python

I want to put a frozenset into itself and to put a tuple into itself.

It seems easy. By writing a simple c++ extension, I was capable to output this:

```py
frozenset({frozenset(...)})
((...),)
```

*... means that object is inside itself*

Is it possible to do the same using just python and it's standard library?

Comment: No. The outer tuple comes into existence after all of its items were evaluated and are therefore defined. Its items must therefore exist before the tuple exists, so the tuple must exist before it exists. Same for frozenset.

Comment: Well, except you are using "ctypes" to manipulate the object in a similar way you probably did in C++.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think, everything is correct, but I want to believe in fairies and a magick trick.

Comment: BTW, what is the hash value of that tuple-in-self created with the C++ extension? Normally it is based on the hash values of the elements. But this one contains itself...

Comment: @MichaelButscher I was hoping on the pickle a bit, but it is written in python, and it just get's RecursionError

Comment: @VPfB for frozenbro: 133146708735736, for tuple: segfault

Comment: This is forbidden at the abstract level of Python. Immutable object cannot modify its internal, but its internal objects must be created before itself.

Comment: @VPfB segfault reason is stackoverflow

Comment: probably possible with ctypes

Comment: @SuperStormer Looks like not very doable from ctypes (I checked:) It segfaults (not the stack overflow), if naively calling 2 functions in a raw... Maybe some other magic is needed to stop it segfaulting

Answer (score 5):

I found another relatively straightforward way to do this, at least for a `tuple`, with the [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html) module for object serialization.

If you don't really care about the "how", then here's a TL;DR one-liner (on Python 3.11.3) which returns a tuple that contains itself:

```
__import__('marshal').loads(b'\xa9\x01\x72\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

---

If you do happen to care about the "how", then the general thrust of the approach is:

1. Figure out how a `tuple` is serialized differently from other container types, such as `list`.
2. Observe how `marshal` serializes a self-containing list, e.g. `[[...]]`.
3. Modify the serialized byte string of `[[...]]` so that it refers to a `tuple` instead, and deserialize it.

Without further ado...

### Step 1

I ran this code, to see how `marshal` serializes a few basic built-in container types:

```
import marshal

L = [1, 2, 3]   # a list
S = {1, 2, 3}   # a set
T = (1, 2, 3)   # a tuple

def show_serial(x): print(x, '=>', marshal.dumps(x).hex(' '))
for x in (L, S, T): show_serial(x)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] => db 03 00 00 00 e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
{1, 2, 3} => bc 03 00 00 00 e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
(1, 2, 3) => a9 03 e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
```

Space the output a little differently, so that things line up:

```
[1, 2, 3] => db 03 00 00 00 e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
{1, 2, 3} => bc 03 00 00 00 e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
(1, 2, 3) => a9 03          e9 01 00 00 00 e9 02 00 00 00 e9 03 00 00 00
```

- Except for the first byte, the bytes for the `list` and the `set` are all identical. That tells me the first byte indicates the **type** of the serialized object.
- Next, the `list` and the `set` have `03 00 00 00` / the `tuple` has just `03`. These bytes indicate the **length** of the container object. As for why the `tuple` only needs 1 byte for its length... I'd guess it's because short tuples e.g. `(x,y)`, `(r,g,b)` are pretty common & this saves space.
- Finally, the last 15 bytes of all three byte strings are identical. These represent the **contents** of each container, i.e. `int(1)`, `int(2)`, and `int(3)`. `e9` denotes a (small) integer, and the remaining 4 bytes of each 5-byte block are the little-endian value of the integer.

### Step 2

Make a self-containing list, and serialize it!

```
L = []; L.append(L); show_serial(L)   # a self-containing list
```

Output:

```
[[...]] => db 01 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00
```

Can I make any sense of this byte string?

- **type**: `type(L) is list`, so first byte is `db` - ✓
- **length**: `len(L) == 1`, so the next 4 bytes are little-endian 1, `01 00 00 00` - ✓
- **contents**: Thus, `72 00 00 00 00` must be a special "this object" indicator for self-referential containers. You can check on this a few other ways as well:

```
L = [1]; L.append(L); show_serial(L)   # a list containing `1` and itself
# output: [1, [...]] => db 02 00 00 00 e9 01 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00

L = 2*[None]; L[0] = L[1] = L; show_serial(L)   # a list containing itself twice
# output: [[...], [...]] => db 02 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00
```

### Step 3

Now I have the needed info to build a byte string which will deserialize to a self-containing `tuple`:

- **type**: I want a `tuple`, so the first byte is `a9`.
- **length**: It should contain 1 element (i.e. itself). Unlike a `list`, a small `tuple` only needs a single byte to serialize its length. So the next byte is `01`.
- **contents**: The only element is the container itself. So the next 5 bytes are `72 00 00 00 00`.

  b = bytes.fromhex('a9 01 72 00 00 00 00')
  T = marshal.loads(b)
  print(T)

Voilà! `T` is a now `tuple` which contains itself!

```
((...),)
```

---

##### Can you use `pickle` to serialize instead of `marshal`?

Doesn't look like it - `pickle` can handle a `list` that contains itself, but it doesn't know how to handle a `tuple` that does the same. I get a `RecursionError` when I try to pickle the tuple created earlier:

```
import pickle
pickle.dumps(T)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selfref.py", line 49, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(T)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

Nor can I see any way one might be able to use `pickle` opcodes to manually put together a byte string & then deserialize that. When it's making a `list`, `pickle` has an `APPEND` opcode to work with... but when it's making a `tuple`, it pushes all the contents of the `tuple` onto the stack first, and then a `TUPLE` opcode. How then can those contents be the `tuple` that doesn't exist yet? Maybe there's a way around this that I'm not seeing - if you know one, then comment & let me know!

##### Can you do the same thing with a `frozenset`?

Unfortunately, this also doesn't seem to work. A `frozenset` serializes the same as a `list` or a `set`, except the first byte is `be` instead of `db` / of `bc`. But `marshal.loads` raises a `ValueError` when I try to deserialize what seems like should be the right byte code...

```
b = bytes.fromhex('be 01 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00')
F = marshal.loads(b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ryant/OneDrive/py/self-referencing-tuple.py", line 43, in <module>
    F = marshal.loads(b)
ValueError: bad marshal data (invalid reference)
```

There's probably some reason I'm missing why this doesn't seem to work, while for a `tuple` it works just fine - please comment if you're aware of one! In the same vein, I'd be interested to know if it's possible to use the `ctypes` method from @SuperStormer's answer to create a `frozenset` which contains itself.

##### What about other `tuple` objects that contain themselves?

You can adapt this technique to create `tuple` objects which contain themselves in more complex patterns - but there are a few more nuances to deal with. Specifically, it looks like `db` / `a9` are not always the `marshal` byte codes for `list` / `tuple` ... when a `list` / a `tuple` is contained in another (different) `list` / `tuple`, for example, the byte code is usually `5b` / `29` instead.

I'm not entirely sure exactly what the different codes & circumstances under which they show up are, and according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html), "Details of the format are undocumented on purpose; it may change between Python versions (although it rarely does)."

For whatever it's worth - here are a couple of hackish functions I came up with, which seem to work pretty well at converting `list` <-> `tuple` for nested sequence types (including ones that contain themselves) with `marshal`:

```
def tupleify(iterable=(), /):
    ''' Converts nested lists to nested tuples '''
    Lb, Tb = iter(marshal.dumps(iterable)), list()
    for byte in Lb:
        if byte in (0xdb, 0x5b):
            length = list(map(next, 4*[Lb]))
            if any(length[1:]):
                Tb += [byte - 0x33] + length
            else:
                Tb += [byte - 0x32] + length[:1]
        else:
            Tb.append(byte)
    return marshal.loads(bytes(Tb))

def listify(iterable=(), /):
    ''' Converts nested tuples to nested lists '''
    Tb, Lb = iter(marshal.dumps(iterable)), list()
    for byte in Tb:
        if byte in (0xa9, 0x29):
            Lb += [byte + 0x32, next(Tb), 0, 0, 0]
        elif byte in (0xa8, 0x28):
            Lb.append(byte + 0x33)
        else:
            Lb.append(byte)
    return marshal.loads(bytes(Lb))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible with ctypes! Note that this code only works properly on 64-bit systems, as it assumes that `ssize_t` and pointers are the same size.

```py
import ctypes

x = (0, )
(ctypes.c_void_p * 4).from_address(id(x))[3] = ctypes.cast(id(x), ctypes.c_void_p)
print(x)
# ((...),)
```

#### Explanation

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* ob_item contains space for 'ob_size' elements.
       Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
       the tuple is not yet visible outside the function that builds it. */
    PyObject *ob_item[1];
} PyTupleObject;
```

(https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/tupleobject.h)

This is the struct definition for tuple objects, straight from the CPython source. Our goal is to override the first element of `ob_item` with a pointer to the tuple itself.

```c
#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD      PyVarObject ob_base;

// ...

struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
};

typedef struct {
    PyObject ob_base;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

(https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/object.h)

We can see that a `PyTupleObject` will contain the following 3 fields prior to the `ob_item` array: `ob_refcnt` (a `ssize_t`), `ob_type` (a pointer) and ob_size (another `ssize_t`) (`_PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA` is only used in debug builds IIRC).

We can take the lazy way out and assume that `ssize_t` and pointers are the same size (which works for 64-bit systems), which lets us treat the `PyTupleObject` as an array of void pointers.

Finally, we change the 4th pointer in this array (which will be the pointer to the first element of the tuple) to point to the address of the tuple itself (which we get via the CPython-specific implementation detail of `id` returning the address of an object).

A proper solution would involve creating custom `ctypes.Structure` classes to represent the structs instead of an system-specific array hack.